# How to populate a Redux-Form select/dropdown from state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

What's the best practice for populating a select/dropdown from state?

I'm populated a redux-form like this...

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';  
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';  
import FormItem from '../FormItem.js';
import FormFooter from '../../components/FormFooter.js';
import Button from '../../components/Button.js';

let UserForm = props => {

  const { handleSubmit, onSubmit } = props;

    return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

            <FormItem
                label = { <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label> }
                field = { <Field name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First name" component="input" className="w-full"/>} 
            />

            <FormItem
                label = { <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label> }
                field = { <Field name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last name" component="input" className="w-full"/> }
            />

            <FormFooter
                left={ <Button href="/users" icon="fa-ban" text="Cancel" /> }
                right={ <button type="submit">Save</button> }
            />

        </form>
    )
}

UserForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'userForm'
})(UserForm)

function mapStateToProps(state) {  
  return { initialValues: state.user.data }
}

UserForm = connect(mapStateToProps
)(UserForm)

export default UserForm
```

Here's the file that includes that form and gets the data:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';  
import PageHeaderBar from '../../components/PageHeaderBar.js';
import PageWrapper from '../PageWrapper.js';
import ContentWrapper from '../ContentWrapper.js';
import { loadUser, updateUser } from '../../actions/users';
import UserAccountForm from './UserAccountForm';
import { Values } from "redux-form-website-template";

class UserAccount extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadUser(localStorage.getItem('userId'));
  }

  handleSubmit(formProps) {
    this.props.updateUser(formProps);
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <PageWrapper>

        <PageHeaderBar title="User profile" />

        <ContentWrapper>
                    <UserAccountForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
                    <Values form="userForm" />
        </ContentWrapper>

      </PageWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { loadUser, updateUser })(UserAccount);
```

Root reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';  
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';  
import authReducer from './auth_reducer';
import userReducer from './user_reducer';
import categoryReducer from './user_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({  
  auth: authReducer,
  form: formReducer,
  user: userReducer.
  category: categoryReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

User reducer:

```
import { LOAD_USER_SUCCESS, LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { data: {} }

export default function (state = {}, action) {  
  switch(action.type) {
    case LOAD_USER_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, data: action.data };
    case LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS:
      console.log('LOAD_USER_SUCCESS');
      return { ...state, data: action.data };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Now I want to add a select to the form above with the following component, and populate it's values from state.category.data. Here's what I have so far...

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';  
import { loadCategories } from '../../actions/categories';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';  
import FormItem from '../FormItem.js';
import VirtualizedSelect from 'react-virtualized-select'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

export const renderSelect = (field) => (
  <VirtualizedSelect
    onChange={field.input.onChange}
    optionHeight={35}
    value={field.input.value}
  />
);

class CategorySelects extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log( 'props' );
    console.log( props.data );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FormItem
        label = { <label htmlFor="type">Category</label> }
        field = { <Field name="type" component={renderSelect} onChange={this.handleTypeChange} /> }
      />
    );
  }
}

export default CategorySelects
```

And I add this to the the form with:

```
<CategorySelects name="categories" />
```

What I'm not sure about is how to populate that select. Right now I just set initialValues on the UserForm with state.user.data. Do I need to merge in the state.category.data as well, or am I going about this the wrong way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding some of your code, but I think your problem is the hard-coded `name` in `CategorySelects`

```
<Field name="type" component={renderSelect} onChange={this.handleTypeChange} />
```

Since you are passing in the name when you add the form via

Then your `Field` on `CategorySelects` should look like this

```
<Field name={props.name} component={renderSelect} onChange={this.handleTypeChange}/>
```

Assuming your `initialValues` looks like

```
{firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Smith", categories: [10, 20, 30] }
```

That would make sure your options are selected, but I don't how you're pushing your options into the component.

If populating your options what you're trying to figure out, then yes, you need to push `state.category.data` into your component, but I wouldn't do it via `redux-form`, I would just pass that data as a prop to `CategorySelects` which would in turn pass it to `VirtualizedSelect` via your `renderSelect` function.

If you user data looks like this, then ignore the whole first part of my answer:

```
{firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Smith", type: 10 }
```

The long and short is that `redux-form` will help you manage the `value` of your forms, but options are something you would take care of in the same manner as using non-redux forms.

Here is the example from the `redux-form` website

```
<Field name="favoriteColor" component="select">
    <option />
    <option value="#ff0000">Red</option>
    <option value="#00ff00">Green</option>
    <option value="#0000ff">Blue</option>
</Field>
```

Is if your initial value object was `{favoriteColor: "#00ff00"}`, then Green would be selected when the component rendered.